# Adding image to JLabel, and displaying Labels in a GridLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel

My current code, interestingly works with another IDE(JGrasp), although I am currently trying to create a game which uses networking.  Eclipse allows networking on a single computer.  For some reason, this method Im posted, which adds imagines to an array of JLabel, does not work with eclipse?  I am new with eclipse and not sure why this is happening?

```
private JPanel createBoard()
{
    // Instantiate Panel with a GridLayout
    board = new JPanel();
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    // Fill the Panel with an Array of Labels
    // Checks for exception
    boardSpotArray = new JLabel[100];
    try
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < boardSpotArray.length; x++)
        {
            boardSpotArray[x] = new JLabel();
            boardSpotArray[x].setIcon(new ImageIcon(x + ".jpg"));
            board.add(boardSpotArray[x]);

        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Array drawer not available, " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    // return panel
    return board;
}
```

Comment: What is the String file path of `x`?

Comment: How is it not working?  What error are you getting?

Comment: the images are located in the same file as the Class.  each image is named 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc..

Comment: Not getting an error, nothing is being displayed, but in other IDE they images are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example `boardSpotArray[0]` is `"firstImage"`, then your relative file path will be `"firstImage.jpg"`. In such a case with Eclipse, and without using any special loaders or resource getters, the IDE will first look for the image in the project root. So your file structure should look like this

```
ProjectRoot
         firstImage.jpg    <-- image as direct child of project root
         src
         bin
```

**Edit:**

If your images are in the `src` folder

```
ProjectRoot
        src
           0.jpg       <-- image in src
           1.jpg
           2.jpg
```

Then your path should look like this

```
new ImageIcon("src/" + x + ".jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the novice question, new to eclipse.

Comment: Okay, yes while being a novice with eclipse, I'm also a novice here on  overstack.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code in Eclipse for you

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class oo {
    public static JPanel createBoard()
    {
        // Instantiate Panel with a GridLayout
        JPanel board = new JPanel();
        board.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

        // Fill the Panel with an Array of Labels
        // Checks for exception
        JLabel[] boardSpotArray = new JLabel[100];
        try
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < boardSpotArray.length; x++)
            {
                boardSpotArray[x] = new JLabel();
                boardSpotArray[x].setIcon(new ImageIcon("healthy-heart.jpg"));
                board.add(boardSpotArray[x]);

            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Array drawer not available, " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        // return panel
        return board;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        JPanel panel=createBoard();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`"healthy-heart.jpg"` can be replaced with any other image.